# TSLint: Property 'params' does not exist on type 'NavigationState'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I use typescript in react-native development. I pass params to screen through `navigate` function.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("NextScreen", { title: "title" })
```

In `NextScreen` I access params through `this.props.navigation.state.params.title` but I get tslint error for `params`.

```
TS2339:Property 'params' does not exist on type 'NavigationState'.
```

This is some of codes.

```
import { NavigationInjectedProps } from "react-navigation";
interface OwnProps {
}
interface OwnState {
}

type Props = NavigationInjectedProps & OwnProps;

class NextScreen extends React.Component<Props, OwnState> {
    ...
    public render() {
        // tslint error occurs in this line.
        const { title } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        ...
    }
}
```

I assume I should define types of passing props but what would be proper approach?

Comment: You need to show all of the relevant code. There just isn't enough here AFAICT to answer your question.

Comment: So just to be clear, the script actually worked, but you were getting a code analysis flag?

Comment: Yes, I get tslint error, not runtime error or crash.

Comment: @Smart Solutions, You should combine your own props and navigation props

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved by this way but I'm not sure if this is the best way.
Researching original code, I redefine `navigation` with custom type  `NavigationScreenProp<NavStateParams>`.

```
import { NavigationInjectedProps, NavigationScreenProp, NavigationState } from "react-navigation";
...
interface ParamType {
  title: string;
}
interface StateParams extends NavigationState {
  params: ParamType;
}
interface OwnProps {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<StateParams>;
}

type Props = OwnProps & NavigationInjectedProps;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract params like this

```
const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;

const title = params.title
```